# web2py db query select showing field name

Tags: select, web2py

When i have the follow query:

```
str(db(db.items.id==int(row)).select(db.items.imageName)) + "\n"
```

The output includes the field name:

```
items.imageName  
homegear\homegear.jpg
```

How do i remove it so that field name will not be included and just the selected imagename.

i tried referencing it like a list [1] gives me an out of range error and [0] i end up with:

```
<Row {'imageName': 'homegear\\homegear.jpg'}>
```

The above is not a list, what object is that and how can i reference on it?

Thanks!

John

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`db(db.items.id==int(row)).select(db.items.imageName)` returns a `Rows` object, and its `__str__` method converts it to CSV output, which is what you are seeing.

A `Rows` object contains `Row` objects, and a `Row` object contains field values. To access an individual field value, you must first index the `Rows` object to extract the `Row`, and then get the individual field value as an attribute of the `Row`. So, in this case, it would be:

```
db(db.items.id==int(row)).select(db.items.imageName)[0].imageName
```

or:

```
db(db.items.id==int(row)).select(db.items.imageName).first().imageName
```

The advantage of `rows.first()` over `rows[0]` is that the former returns `None` in case there are no rows, whereas the latter will generate an exception (this doesn't help in the above case, because the subsequent attempt to access the `.imageName` attribute would raise an exception in either case if there were no rows).

Note, even when the select returns just a single row with a single field, you still have to explicitly extract the row and the field value as above.